# C - Split tokens into several arrays of token

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, token

I spent quite at time thinking about this problem but haven't found an answer yet. I had some solutions but they all generated memory leaks....

I have these functions:

```
char *read_line(void)
{
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t bufsize = 0; 
  getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
  return line;

}

#define BUFSIZE 64
#define DELIM " \t\r\n\a" 
char **split_line(char *line)
{
  int bufsize = BUFSIZE;
  int position = 0;
  char **argumentlist = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
  char *argument;

  if (!argumentlist) {
    fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  argument = strtok(line, DELIM);
  while (argument != NULL) 
  {
    argumentlist[position] = argument;
    position++;

    if (position >= bufsize) 
    {
      bufsize += SP_BUFSIZE;
      argumentlist = realloc(argumentlist, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!argumentlist) 
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    argument = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
  }

  argumentlist[position] = NULL; //null terminates list of arguments

  return argumentlist; //array of arguments
}
```

So i have now a array with tokens. The problem is now that I want to split this array of tokens into smaller arrays for using shell commands. For example if somebody types: "ls -l | sort" I need two arrays; one with the tokens: "ls -l NULL" and the other one with "sort NULL" ==>

```
token1[0] = ls
token1[1] = -l
token1[2] = NULL

token2[0] = sort
token2[1] = NULL
```

I need these arrays for the execvp command. Or if someone types: "ls -l < test.txt > hello.txt" i should get the two arrays with the token: "ls -l NULL" and "test.txt hello.txt NULL". So I want to make a function which takes a char** and creates token arrays by looking for ">" "<" or "|" as delimeters.

I hope this unterstandable, I'm really kind of stuck I don't know how to move on without generating memory leaks.

Comment: You only get memory leaks if you don't free what you've allocated. So make sure that every allocation is matched with a free. That's independent of the logic of your program. To simplify the logic of your program, write some functions: the simplest way to make code easy to read and write is to make common operations independent functions. For example, a function which adds a string to an array of strings.

Comment: whatever, if your tokens are (let set) `{"ls", "-l", "|", "sort", NULL}` what is complicated? Just loop on the elements until you reach a "|", a "<" or a ">". You will have to create a table of tables of tables, whatever (one for each token1, token2…, with inside one for each token, with inside the char*).

Comment: note that your code will not work if you don't put spaces beetween "|"/"<"/">" (i.e. "ls -l |sort", where the last token will be "|sort").

Comment: when `realloc()` fails, this line: `argumentlist = realloc(argumentlist, bufsize * sizeof(char*));` overlays the prior pointer with a NULL, resulting in a memory leak.  Before calling `exit()`, need to cleanup by passing allocated memory to `free()`, closing any open file descriptors, etc

Comment: what is `SP_BUFSIZE`?   Perhaps you meant: `BUFSIZE`.

Comment: the memory allocation performed by `getline()` also needs to be passed to `free()` before calling `exit()`

Comment: regarding the generation of the new arrays for the commands,  Perhaps you need to ask:  do I actually need to break the line into tokens?  and what happens when the user input is: `ls -al>newfile` or `ls    -al    >   newfile` or ` echo "alpha - betta"` or similar.   In other words, the current method of breaking the line into tokens does not work correctly for all cases.   A usable tokenizer needs to parse the input char by char, with a number of 'states' that indicate if in a token (and what kind of token) or just in some white space between tokens